# Set Union in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pandas, vectorization

I have two columns which I stored sets in my dataframe.

I want to perform set union on the two columns using fast vectorized operation

```
df['union'] = df.set1 | df.set2
```

but the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'set' and 'bool'` is preventing me from doing so as I have type `np.nan` in both columns.

Is there a good solution to overcome this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For these operations pure Python is generally more efficient.

```
%timeit pd.Series([set1.union(set2) for set1, set2 in zip(df['A'], df['B'])])
10 loops, best of 3: 43.3 ms per loop

%timeit df.apply(lambda x: x.A.union(x.B), axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.6 s per loop
```

---

DataFrame for timings:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
l1 = [set(np.random.choice(list('abcdefg'), np.random.randint(1, 5))) for _ in range(100000)]
l2 = [set(np.random.choice(list('abcdefg'), np.random.randint(1, 5))) for _ in range(100000)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': l1, 'B': l2})
```

Comment: Won't this hit the same issue when the value in either `A` or `B` is `np.nan`?

Answer (score 5):

This is the best I could come up with:

```
# method 1
df.apply(lambda x: x.set1.union(x.set2), axis=1)

# method 2
df.applymap(list).sum(1).apply(set)
```

#### Wow!

I expected the method 2 to be quicker.  Not so!

[image]

#### Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}] for _ in range(3)],
                  columns=list('AB'))
df
```

[image]

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.set1.union(x.set2), axis=1)

0    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
1    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
2    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Comment: Excuse my limited pandas knowledge, but what would union mean for dataframe columns? Won't that reset the order in which the output column be produced and also would have more elements? Can you add a sample case, if that's not too much of trouble?

Comment: Yes, I'll put something up in a bit.  However, the `apply` with `axis=1` means this gets run iteratively over rows.  So that `lambda` operates on `pd.Series` objects.  So `x.set1` is the actual set in `set1`'s location for that row.  Same for `set2`.  That union is the actual `set.union` method.

Comment: @Divakar Also, I qualified this as the best I could come up with because this is terrible.  Why can't we do something with `np.union1d`?

Comment: After thinking about it some more, maybe method #1 isn't so terrible.

Comment: Thanks for the updates! Makes sense now. Also, I was thinking about using NumPy, but then the union might result in different number of elems per row, so I don't think it would be worth it. So, I think that `apply` method should be the best one.